# Semi-automatic classification plugin - Preprocessing problem

Tags: qgis, scp

I am trying to use the SCP plugin in QGIS 3.16.15.

I downloaded Sentinel-2 images from ESA's open data hub, which I added to a band set (only 4 bands of interest), and then clipped to the region of interest (using the plugins own "clip multiple raster" tool).
When I get to the preprocessing step, I input the path to the clipped images into the relevant box and nothing happens, as if the plugin does not find the images in the previously set directory. Nothing appears in the bottom box, where all bands are supposed to get listed (see image).

[image: SCP plugin screenshot]

Is this a problem with the plugin or with the way I input the data? Has someone had the same problem?

It all seems so easy in all the tutorials, yet it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I'm not sure which tool you use. However, in my experience, these clip problems are caused by mismatches in the coordinate systems of the two objects to be clipped. Match the coordinates of your region of interest (polygon) with the Sentinel 2 coordinate system.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. The problem is not with SCP's "clip multiple raster" tool, but the image preprocessing itself. It is as if the SCP does not recognise the .tif files in the specified directory, and therefore does not list them in the relevant box (see screenshot). Because they do not appear in the box, clicking the "Run" button does not yield any results.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it reads only three clipped rasters instead of reading the whole 12 layers. I think those three-layer, all have 20meters pixle size

Answer (score 0):

This same problem has happened to me. I have managed to identify that it occurs by the name of the file containing each band. When you download the bands directly from the Copernicus these appear the description of the spatial resolution at the end of the name of each file. e.g. 10,m, 20m and 60m. If you delete this part of the file name the problem is solved.